# Use two JOINs on the same table in sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, join

I have a query like below which is working fine.

```
SELECT 
    "A".id AS A_id,
    "B".id AS B_id,
    "C".id AS C_id,
    "D".id AS D_id,
    "E".id AS E_id,
    "F".id AS F_id,
    "G".id AS G_id,
    "H".id AS H_id,
    "I".id AS I_id
FROM "A" 
INNER JOIN "B" ON "A".id = "B".A_id 
INNER JOIN "C" ON "B".C_id = "C".id
INNER JOIN "D" ON "C".D_id = "D".id
INNER JOIN "E" ON "D".id = "E".D_id
INNER JOIN "F" ON "E".F_id = "F".id
INNER JOIN "G" ON "F".G_id = "G".id
INNER JOIN "H" ON "G".id = "H".G_id
INNER JOIN "I" ON "H".I_id = "I".id;
```

Now I would like to add special condition. Table "B" is connected with another table
and I have to add special join (full join) but after all joins. Something like below
(it`s not working of course):

```
SELECT 
    "A".id AS A_id,
    "B".id AS B_id,
    "C".id AS C_id,
    "D".id AS D_id,
    "E".id AS E_id,
    "F".id AS F_id,
    "G".id AS G_id,
    "H".id AS H_id,
    "I".id AS I_id,
    "Setup".id AS setup_id,
    "Run".id AS run_id
FROM "A" 
INNER JOIN "B" ON "A".id = "B".A_id 
INNER JOIN "C" ON "B".C_id = "C".id
INNER JOIN "D" ON "C".D_id = "D".id
INNER JOIN "E" ON "D".id = "E".D_id
INNER JOIN "F" ON "E".F_id = "F".id
INNER JOIN "G" ON "F".G_id = "G".id
INNER JOIN "H" ON "G".id = "H".G_id
INNER JOIN "I" ON "H".I_id = "I".id

AND FROM
"Setup" 
FULL JOIN "Run" ON "Setup".id = "Run".id
FULL JOIN "B" ON "Setup".id = "B".id;
```

I used full join because each of the table "Run" and "Setup" include only one row but are connected with table "B" which has got more that one row and I want to have all of them in the result table.

How to repair it? Maybe try to use select in select?

Comment: I don't understand. There is exactly one setup record for each B rechord? And exactly one run record for each setup record? Then just use inner joins and that's it.

Comment: You probably need to `LEFT JOIN` these tables, and not full joins.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a full join to get multiple rows reflected in the 1 to many relationships you describe. another inner join. And there is no "AND FROM" construction. You can simple add the joins directly.

```
INNER JOIN "I" ON "H".I_id = "I".id
INNER JOIN "Setup" ON "B".id = "Setup".id;
INNER JOIN "Run" ON "Setup".id = "Run".id
```

You should probably read-up on [joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

[EDIT]

Comment indicate the data is asymmetric such that you do need an outer join, so:

```
INNER JOIN "I" ON "H".I_id = "I".id
LEFT JOIN "Setup" ON "B".id = "Setup".id;
LEFT JOIN "Run" ON "Setup".id = "Run".id
```

Comment: I think he needs left joins.

Comment: I thought so a first, but when I read it more closely I think it is really only inner joins. I could be wrong.

Comment: I can use LEFT or FULL join. Above answers help me. The result 
with INNER JOIN is
` tombinput_id | setup_id | run_id 
--------------+----------+--------
            1 |        1 |      1`
with FULL or LEFT JOIN is
` tombinput_id | setup_id | run_id 
--------------+----------+--------
            4 |          |       
            1 |        1 |      1
            2 |          |       
            3 |          |       `
without some fields in select to more transparent view.

Comment: You need a a OUTER JOIN (LEFT or RIGHT) is if you are "missing" related columns in one side or the other. It sounded form the description that the Setup and Run records would exist, so an INNER would do in that case. The data in the previous comments proves otherwise. A FULL OUTER combines both LEFT and RIGHT joins, but we give the same results as one or the other depending on what is missing or not.